# Configurable swatches are not displaying on new products page ( new.phtml )

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, rwd-theme, color-swatches, new-products

I am using my custom theme. By following some articles, I have displayed configurable swatches on the product list page.

When I set the configurable product as New then it appears on my New Products Page. i.e. I have used following code for my New Products Page:

> {{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new"
>   column_count="4" products_count="0" alias="product_new"
>   template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}

But on this page configurable swatches are not displaying

I activated **RWD theme** but there also configurable swatches are not displaying on New Products Page.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As **new.phtml**  is a different template you need to integrate swatches manually like you did for your custom theme  listing page

Comment: I made some changes to catalog.xml also. can you tell me in which layout file changes should be done?